# Count cells with background color

Tags: numbers

In a range of cells, is there any way of counting the ones with certain background color?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in **AppleScript** that will *count* the number of *cells* in a *range* that has the *background color* of red.

[image: Numbers Image]

Note that the target **Numbers** *document* was open and in the background of **Script Editor**.

When the *script* was run, it displayed the following dialog box.

[image: Display Dialog Image]

```
--  # User definded variables.

set theRange to "A1:L10"

--  # The background color of the range’s cells. Expressed as a list of RGB (Red, Green, Blue) 
--  #  values, from 0 to 65535. For example, the color red is: {65535, 0, 0}

set R to 65535
set G to 0
set B to 0


--  # Other variables.

set thisColor to ""
set theRGBValue to {}
set theCount to 0


tell application "Numbers"
    tell document 1
        tell sheet 1
            tell table 1
                tell range theRange
                    repeat with i from 1 to (cell count)
                        set thisColor to background color of cell i as string
                        if thisColor is not "" then
                            set theRGBValue to (background color of cell i)
                            if item 1 of theRGBValue is equal to R and item 2 of theRGBValue is equal to G and item 3 of theRGBValue is equal to B then
                                set theCount to theCount + 1
                            end if
                        end if
                    end repeat
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

display dialog "The cell count with the color {" & R & ", " & G & ", " & B & "} is: " & theCount buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

Note: This was tested on an old version of **Numbers** (09 ver 2.3) and may need to be adjusted for newer versions.

If you do not know what the **RGB** *value* of a given `cell` is, to plug into the *script* above, then to get the **RGB** *value* of the `background color` of a given `cell`, e.g. `F5`, use:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    get background color of cell 1 of range "F5:F5" of table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1
end tell
```

Just an FYI, I coded the main example further above in the long form and it could be condensed down to the following for the `tell application "Numbers"` *block*:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    tell range theRange of table 1 of sheet 1 of document 1
        repeat with i from 1 to (cell count)
            if (background color of cell i as string) is not "" then
                set theRGBValue to (background color of cell i)
                if item 1 of theRGBValue is equal to R and item 2 of theRGBValue is equal to G and item 3 of theRGBValue is equal to B then
                    set theCount to theCount + 1
                end if
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```